# Oracle Format Number With Commas Remove Trailing Zero Decimals

Tags: oracle

In my query, I am trying to output numbers with commas but I would like to remove all trailing zeroes after the decimal place. For example:

3132000.00 -> 3,132,000

4321.10 -> 4,321.1

132.01 -> 132.01

I have been using TO_CHAR and I cannot have commas without getting .00 at the end of the number. A few examples I have tried:

TO_CHAR(3132000, '999G999G990D00')) -> 3,132,000.00 -> WHAT I WANT: 3,132,000

TO_CHAR(1080000, 'TM')) -> 1080000 -> WHAT I WANT: 1,080,000

I have searched high and low for the answer but I have not found a way to have commas and remove zero decimals which amazes me. How would I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you. The format `'999G990D00'` will not produce the result 3,132,000.00. Rather, it may show something like `######`. Why? Because the format has only six digits for the integral part, and the value has seven. If you want to be taken seriously, post examples that are correct.

Comment: I switched my field with a random number and didn’t update the format. I updated my question so I don’t offend anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, if you must use group separators and decimal separator in the format model, even with the `'fm'` format model modifier (to make the output as "short" as possible) the decimal point will survive, even if the input is an integer. That is because Oracle interprets the `D` as a mandatory character (decimal separator) in the output.

We may wish that the designers of Oracle were smarter, and they would have included "remove the decimal point for integers" when they defined the `'fm'` modifier. They weren't.

Other than that, there are a couple of mistakes in your attempt. You show examples where the integral part has seven digits, but you included only six in the format model. (You **must** include enough digits in the format model to accommodate the largest numbers in your input data.) You also used 0 in the decimal part, even though you don't want 0 shown if it is not needed. Those should be 9 instead.

So: the best you can do without extra work (but do read on for "extra work" solutions too) is:

```
with
  inputs (num) as (
    select 3132000.000 from dual union all
    select    4321.10  from dual union all
    select     132.01  from dual union all
    select 1080000     from dual
  )
select num, to_char(num, 'fm999G999G999D99') as str
from   inputs
;

          NUM STR            
------------- ---------------
      3132000 3,132,000.     
         4321 4,321.1        
          132 132.01         
      1080000 1,080,000.
```

Notice the ugly decimal point after the integers. As I explained, you can't address that directly in the format model.

Here is one way to fix that (with extra work after the fact):

```
with
  inputs (num) as (
    select 3132000.000 from dual union all
    select    4321.10  from dual union all
    select     132.01  from dual union all
    select 1080000     from dual
  )
select num, rtrim(to_char(num, 'fm999G999G999D99'), '.') as str
from   inputs
;

          NUM STR            
------------- ---------------
      3132000 3,132,000      
         4321 4,321.1        
          132 132.01         
      1080000 1,080,000
```

However, this is pretty annoying - I shouldn't have to do any such work after the fact. Is there a way to do some prep BEFORE using TO_CHAR?

The answer is YES - I can use a `case` expression in the format model parameter. For logical purity I prefer this version:

```
with
  inputs (num) as (
    select 3132000.000 from dual union all
    select    4321.10  from dual union all
    select     132.01  from dual union all
    select 1080000     from dual
  )
select num, to_char(num, case when num = trunc(num) then 'fm999G999G999'
                                    else 'fm999G999G999D99' end) as str
from   inputs
;

          NUM STR            
------------- ---------------
      3132000 3,132,000      
         4321 4,321.1        
          132 132.01         
      1080000 1,080,000
```

Comment: BIG LIKE:"We may wish that the designers of Oracle were smarter"
Thank you for the helpful and very thorough answer!

Comment: Amazing answer. I had to look for a while to find out info on that trailing decimal separator, and the case when in the to_char is an elegant fix.